# Pincipal component analysis with R

Tags: r, pca

So I run PCA on my data and always find this error: Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

I've removed the NAs, removed the duplicated rows, but I still get the error

```
log.neur <- log(neur[, 2:65])
neu.pca <- prcomp(log.neur,
             center = TRUE,
             scale. = TRUE)
```

> Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by `Inf` values left in your data, as the typical usage of `na.rm = TRUE` does not account for this.

The following commands should get things working:

```
log.neur <- log(neur[, 2:65])
log.neur[!is.finite(log.neur)] = -1 # baseline value
neu.pca <- prcomp(log.neur, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
```

where I have arbitrarily set a value of -1 in place of the missing/invalid data. You might have to change that based on how the data looks like